# Replace patterns on file except one line in it

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I am looking for a solution to replace one pattern on a file except one line in it.

For example:
zone file:

```
> cat /var/named/test.com.db
; cPanel first:11.11.0-BETA_16994 (update_time):1468656855 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:server.test.com latest:11.56.0.13
; Zone file for test.com
$TTL 14400
test.com.      86400   IN      SOA     ns1.test.com.     cpanel.test.com.  (
                                                2016071602 ;Serial Number
                                                14400 ;refresh
                                                7200 ;retry
                                                2419200 ;expire
                                                43200   )

test.com.      14400   IN      A       192.168.1.100

localhost       14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1

test.com.      14400   IN      MX      0       test.com.

mail    14400   IN      CNAME   test.com.
www     14400   IN      CNAME   test.com.
ftp     14400   IN      CNAME   test.com.
webdisk 14400   IN      A       192.168.1.100
cpcalendars     14400   IN      A       192.168.1.100
test.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:192.168.1.100 ~all"
```

I want to replace all current IP address **192.168.1.100** in it with **192.168.1.101** except the "spf" record line.

How can this be done?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '/spf/! s/192\.168\.1\.100/192.168.1.101/'
```

On lines which do not match `/spf/` do the requested substitution.  The backslashes prevent the `.` from matching any character, of course.  If you have any lines where the IP address could appear multiple times, you could add a `g` at the end.  If you think it is a real problem, you could worry about matching `9192.168.1.1001` (that is, you if you think the IP address might appear as a substring of something that isn't an IP address).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sed -i -r 's/192.168.1.100$/192.168.1.101/g' /var/named/test.com.db
```

Comment: Hi, it worked.
But could you explain what's the part "192.168.1.100$" actually doing? and how it excludes SPF line?. Curious to know :)

Comment: @johnwilson: The `$` requires the match at the end of the line; the IP address doesn't appear at the end of the line in the `spf` line.  The `g` is redundant; there can only ever be one match at the end of line.